# space after characters with carons

Tags: accents, font-encodings

If I write `ďalej` or `ťaťa`, there is a little space after characters `ď` and `ť` (and also `ľ`). Is it possible to remove this space ?

I'm using `cp1250` encoding and Slovak `babel`.

Can somebody help, please ?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[dp]{FEIstyle}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
ďalej ťa
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added the code

Answer (score 6):

The kerning in the European Modern fonts is not ideal, I'm afraid. You solve the issue by loading the Latin Modern fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
ďalej ťa
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. But when I use \usepackage{lmodern}, the font changes. Is it somehow possible to do it without changing font to latin modern ?

Comment: @user2778945 No, I'm afraid. However the differences between Latin Modern and Computer (or European) Modern fonts are not that big; since the former have better glyphs for Slovak…